# Fujitsu IPMI fan speed control

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool, fan

My goal is to reduce the noise and save a little bit of power of my Fujitsu Primergy RX300 S6.

I am using Proxmox as my OS and already installed "ipmitool" which works great for reading sensor data.

I tried following this guide(https://www.spxlabs.com/blog/2019/3/16/silence-your-dell-poweredge-server) to lower the fan speed.
Unfortunately the ipmi raw commands do not work on my server (I thought ipmi is standardized).

When I try to run `ipmitool raw 0x30 0x30 0x01 0x00` in order to enable manual fan control, I get the follwing error:
`Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x0 netfn=0x30 lun=0x0 cmd=0x30 rsp=0xc7): Request data length invalid`

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this or could provide me a source of the approriate ipmi raw codes.

Thanks a lot in advance, Varsius

Comment: IPMI is standard enough, but vendor-specific extensions are not. And just about anything you do with raw will be vendor-specific.

Comment: @MichaelHampton do you have any idea where I can find these vendor-specific commands? I searched a lot but did not find any

Comment: For a Fujitsu server? If searching the net and asking the vendor doesn't get you anywhere...